# Проблемы с добавлением сертификата charles на mac

Tags: proxy, сертификат, charles

Я хочу добавить сертификат charles на mac, но при этом после нажатия кнопки добавить ничего не происходит сертификата в связке ключей так и не появляется

Comment: такая же проблема
где искать другой серт?

Comment: так а куда нажимать , случалась такая же проблема )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге оказалось что у меня был записан где то в настройках старый сертификат, я его удалил и добавил новый, если с этим будут проблемы - пишите расскажу подробнее куда нажимать